How to fit a binomial model with repeated observations per subject
I have a small dataset for 100 participants.
The dataset includes repeated 'tests' over a course of a week. A test can have the binary outcome of pass or fail, and the same number of tests are not necessarily completed each day, but all counts are known. Additionally, there covariates, some of which change, for example 'day', and 'mood', while others remain the same as they are measured at the start of the week ('weight', 'height'). I would like to model this proportion data.



ID
day
count_tests
pass
prop
mood
height
weight




1
1
24
18
0.75
1
127
74.5


1
2
23
20
0.87
2
127
74.5


1
3
24
17
0.71
2
127
74.5


1
4
20
17
0.85
1
127
74.5


1
5
21
20
0.95
2
127
74.5


......
.....
.............
......
......
......
........
........


100
1
23
20
0.87
1
190
82


100
2
24
18
0.75
3
190
82


100
3
18
9
0.5
2
190
82


100
4
21
4
0.19
1
190
82


100
5
23
20
0.87
3
190
82



I do have 15 rows out of 750 where the proportion is equal to 0 or 1. These proportions are the result of a small number of tests (<=10) being performed on that day, for example:



ID
day
count_tests
pass
prop
mood
height
weight




50
1
1
1
1.0
1
120
70


68
7
2
0
0
1
135
66


79
1
6
0
0
2
145
90.4


8
1
10
10
1.0
1
127
74.5



As per advice in a pervious question, a binomial model appears to be a suitable choice for this data. I have little statistical experience, so I am would really appreciate some feedback about if I am on the right track. Building off of this post, would the following approach with a random effect for the ID be appropriate:
glmer(pass/count_tests ~ day+mood+height+weight + (1|ID), myData, 
    family="binomial")

Additionally, do I need to incorporate weights or account for overdispersion with this data?

This is a reasonable start. I expect that mood a categorical variable? For example, mood = 1 means "calm". Then you should make declare is as a factor or otherwise R would treat it as a continuous variable. For example: glmer(pass/count_tests ~ day + factor(mood) + height + weight + (1|ID), ...).

Something else to explore: Right now the effect of time is the same for all participants (and it's linear -- also a strong assumption). You could consider a random-intercept, random-slope model with glmer(pass/count_tests ~ day + factor(mood) + height + weight + (1 + day|ID), ...).

Thank you @dipetkov! I appreciate your input, particularly around the effect of time

Once you fit the model, you would want to run some diagnostics on it. For example using the {DHARMa} package. There're many CV threads on the topic of model diagnostics as well.
